# Unity 2D rotating child object in compound collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have two game objects, player and gun. Player has dynamic RigidBody 2D and gun has Box Collider 2D and set it as the child of Player. Here, Unity documentation says

> When you create a compound collider like this, you should only use one Rigidbody
>    component, placed on the root object in the hierarchy.

I have RigidBody 2D component in Parent and I want to rotate the gun, the child, but it has no RigidBody2D.  I can't rotate with its transform component because it's under physics engine control. How can I rotate the child object in this case?

Comment: If you need your gun to react to physic (in what sense ?), you should have a rigidbody on it. A compound collider is just multiple collider "added" together to work out collision, I don't think that's what you want

Comment: @Jichael I want my gun to react physics, example, collide with enemy bullets. But I can't add rigidbody to it because it's a child.